# Event for iphone goes to sleep automatically

Tags: ios, events, sleep

Which Event for iOS gets called when iphone goes into sleep mode **AUTOMATICALLY** while any iOS app is running ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```